# How to select values with decimals > 0 in a field?

Tags: python, pyqgis

I'm trying to write a script that would select the features which have the decimal value in the field 'Length' greater than 0.

Here's what I could think about it:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import re

layer = iface.activeLayer()

selected_fid = []
r = re.compile(r"^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$")

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if r.match(feat['Length']):
        selected_fid.append(feat.id())
    break

layer.select(selected_fid)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 12, in 
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I've read about using re for this purpose, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714/regex-greater-than-zero-with-2-decimal-places but I'm not sure how to integrate this with the PyQGIS selection function.

Comment: Beside the typo in the field name, you would have to convert it to a string if it is a numerical field. That being said, you may want to investigate a pure mathematical approach, like `field - round(field) <> 0`

Comment: Change this `layer.select(selected_fid)` to this `layer.selectByIds(selected_fid)` as described [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a450a58921855552f4a6710c995d5d87b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by JGH, the 'Length' field needs to be read as string in order for RegEx to work, so many thanks to him for that notice. I post here working version:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import re

layer = iface.activeLayer()

selected_fid = []
r = re.compile(r"\d*\.0*[1-9]+\d*")

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if r.match(str(feat['Length'])):
        selected_fid.append(feat.id())
    else:
        print ''

layer.select(selected_fid)
```

**The above RegEx can be tested here:** https://regex101.com/r/TwjAsg/1